# JMeter multiple header manager issue

Tags: jmeter

I'm creating a record using post method from one user & verifying record with another user using Get method so for this I need 2 different tokens so what I did that I have used one Header Manager at the thread level & another Header Manager at HTTP-Request level now problem is that when I am running this Get API will get called & in the request header token of both user is getting passed. Can anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: I am not clear about your questions can you brief it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Header Manager obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/), so if you place it at the same level as [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - it will be applied to all Samplers.

If you add a HTTP Header Manager **as a child of the Sampler** - it will be applied to that Sampler **only**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need separate Header Manager per HTTP request, put each Header Manager **under each HTTP request** and not on thread level so it only affect the relevant request